# Qt Regex Help (Array Keys)

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qt-creator

Okay, so the following string is what my regex will attempt to match against:

```
[key1][key2][key3]
```

and here is my regex.

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

This is all being done in Qt, and here is the code I am using

```
QRegExp reg("\\[(.+?)\\]");
reg.indexIn(string);
qDebug() << "Matches: " << reg.capturedTexts();
```

The above returns this:

```
("", "")
```

So two questions then:

1. Why are the captures empty
2. On my regex, why did I need to put \\ for it to work? If I just put \ it will not capture anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you try `\\[([^\\]]+)\\]` instead?

Comment: Okay, I got key1, but now how do I get the other 2? reg.captureCount() returns 1.

Comment: is there any way to turn on global modifier?

Comment: I tried doing /.../g , but that returned a NULL string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's optimize your regular expression: instead of `.+?` reluctant expression use `[^\]]+`, which lets you avoid so-called [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). The new expression is as follows:

```
\\[([^\\]]+)\\]
```

> On my regex, why did I need to put `\\` for it to work?

Because the regex goes through two compilers which pay attention to backslashes - first, your C++ compiler, and then the regex compiler inside `QRegExp` constructor. The first slash of the pair is for the C++ compiler; the second one is for the regex compiler. Once C++ compiler is finished, each pair of backslahses is replaced with a single slash, which is what the regex needs.

> I got `key1`, but now how do I get the other 2? `reg.capturedCount()` returns 1

Your regular expression captures one square bracket - delimited item at a time. If you want to capture them all, you need a loop:

```
int pos = 0;
while (pos >= 0) {
     pos = reg.indexIn(str, pos);
     if (pos >= 0) {
         ++pos;      // move along in str
         qDebug() << "Matches: " << reg.capturedTexts();
     }
}
```